# PostgreSQL Получение True и False вместо t и f

Tags: postgresql

Есть запрос:

`SELECT name as customername, active as customeractive FROM customers`

Данный запрос возвращает результат customeractive в виде t или f.

Подскажите, каким образом сделать так, чтобы вместо этого возвращались логические TRUE и FALSE соответственно?

Comment: Куда возвращает?

Answer (score 0):

это уже логические true/false, просто так их отображает posgres
если не верите, можете проверить:

```
select true from customers
```

Однако если customeractive не bool а char, можно преобразовать так:

```
SELECT name as customername, case active when 'f' then false else true end as customeractive FROM customers
```

Comment: наверняка у афтора в колонке `active` хранится `true`|`false`. а при выполнении запроса в консоль выдаёт 't' и 'f'. даже если ваше сравнение и сработает чудесным образом, то в результате будет опять 't' и 'f':)

Comment: скорее всего так и есть, поэтому первая часть ответа и была написана :)

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev правильно ли я понимаю, что при получении результата запроса в виде массива, допустим, в php, нам придется вручную приводить значение из строкового "t" в логическое "true"?

Comment: @SryForStupidQuestion, проверьте для своей библиотеки доступа. PDO сам преобразует значение в нативный для PHP тип bool.